# What does ' above a value represent?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation

For example p' being compared to p

I believe it means "p prime" and is used to denote a different value than p?

I apologize if it has been answered before but I am unable to find it using a quotation mark.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Give us more context. Sometimes it's a derivative, sometimes it's just another symbol to distinguish from another.

Comment: A photo might help.

Comment: It's just another variable, but, as the notation indicates, it is meant to be related to the variable $p.$ So, at least when writing sanely,  if $p$ is a price, then $p'$ should be a price. If $p$ is a probability, then $p'$ should be a probability. (This assumes that you aren't talking calculus, where $p'$ might be the derivative.) As a rule, this can lead to potential confusion in some contexts, so you might try other variables, like $p_0?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In real or complex analysis $f'$ is the derivative of a function $f$. In algebra $f'$ is also the formal derivative of a polynomial $f$.

In other contexts, the 'prime' is used to distinguish between two objects of the same nature that are related in some way. For example, a triangle that is similar to another triangle $ABC$ is usually named $A'B'C'$, when $\hat A=\hat A'$, $\hat B=\hat B'$, etc. Or, if $a,b$ are positive integers and their gcd is $d$, $a'=a/d$ and $b'=b/d$.

Anyway, have in mind that there is no organization that dictates the notations for maths, as IUPAC is for chemistry and physics, for example.

Comment: Continuing the triangle case $A',B',C'$ is rather often the center of sides $BC,CA,AB$ resp. In other contexts (computer languages) $A'$ for example means "transposition" of $A$. In boolean algebra, $p'$ may have the meaning of negation of $p$.

Comment: Yes. As I have said, there is some anarchy in mathematical notation. Perhaps there are too many things to name to do it sistematically.

Comment: Is it read as p prime?